# change cloud foundry default admin's scope

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I follow this guide http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/uaa-user-management.html to create another user but accidentally update the default admin's scope to 'EXISTING-PERMISSIONS scim.write' in step 7. After that, when I try to update the scope back using './uaac client update admin --authorities' command I got following error:

```
error response:  
{  
  "error": "access_denied",  
  "error_description": "Invalid token does not contain resource id (clients)"  
}
```

Does anyone know how to restore default admin's scope back? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have another admin user, you might be stuck.  I suppose you could connect to the database and manually update the scopes / authorities.  Another option would be to redeploy CF, but unless you're using bosh-lite and running locally that would probably not be an option.

Comment: Thank you! Fortunately I can redeploy CF and it fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

Senior Field Engineer from Pivotal here.

You can recover the admin account's group membership by connecting to the postgres UAAdb leveraging credentials in OpsMgr or your deployment manifest. Below are sample scripts you may use with the needed groups. Don't worry about duplicate rows as the PK constraint blocks them. Once the groups have been updated, use BOSH to do a rolling reboot of your UAA server. This needs to be done to clear the in-memory cache of UAA... unfortunately there is not a more elegant way. Hope this helps.

```
--client.write
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='clients.write'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--clients.admin
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='clients.admin'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--scim.read
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='scim.read'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--scim.write
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='scim.write'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--password.write
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='password.write'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--clients.read
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='clients.read'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');

--uaa.admin
insert into group_membership values ((select id from groups where displayname='uaa.admin'), (select id from users where username='admin'), 'USER', 'MEMBER', '2015-01-05', 'uaa');
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP must have changed the admin client's authorities, not the scopes of the admin user. This would be the statement to run:

```
update oauth_client_details set authorities = 'uaa.admin,clients.read,clients.write,clients.secret,scim.read,scim.write,clients.admin' where client_id = 'admin'
```